# Using addition probability rule and multiplication probability rule with less than symbol

Tags: probability

How can we apply the following two rules with the less than symbol?

Addition probability rule: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)$

Multiplication probability rule: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$

Let:

$P(Y) ≤ 0.5$

$P(X) ≤ 0.5$

1- What is the probability either $Y$ or $X$ occur? ($0.75$ is a wrong answer)

2- What is the probability both $Y$ and $X$ occur? ($0.25$ is a wrong answer)

Comment: The first means that $P[X]$ is $0.5$, the second means it could be anywhere in the range $[0, 0.5]$. I'm not sure I understand the confusion.

Comment: how can we apply the following two rules with the less than symbol

       1- addition probability rule: P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P( B | A )

2- multiplication probability rule: P(A ∩ B) = P(A) P(B|A)

Comment: You have two questions as this is phrased. One is asking if $\le$ can be used with the probability operator. The answer is yes. The other is asking how to generalise two laws of probability

Comment: What has that to do with the question? Oh whoa, you changed the question quite a bit.

Comment: For events $X, Y$ you know that $P[X \cup Y] = P[X] + P[Y] - P[X \cap Y]$.  If you are only told $P[X]\leq 0.5$ and $P[Y]\leq 0.5$ then you can conclude only that $0.5 \leq P[X \cup Y] \leq 1$, and in fact it is possible for $P[X \cup Y]$ to take any value in that interval $[0.5, 1]$ (so $0.75$ is possible but not necessarily true).

Comment: Thanks Michael! what about X and Y? is it correct to assume, [∩] would be in the interval [0, 0.25] ?

Comment: I think you are asking what range of values $P[X \cap Y]$ can take if we are only told $X, Y$ are events that satisfy $P[X]\leq 0.5$ and $P[Y] \leq 0.5$.  Perhaps you can try to construct example events $X$ and $Y$ that make $P[X \cap Y]$ as large as you can, and then, as small as you can.  You might take the probability experiment as rolling a dice, so the sample space is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ with all outcomes equally likely. Can you make events $X, Y$ so that $P[X]\leq 0.5$, $P[Y] \leq 0.5$, but $P[X \cap Y] > 0.25$?

Comment: I do not think that would be possible.  since the greatest value for [] = 0.5, the greatest value for [] = 0.5, then 0.5X0.5 = 0.25 would the upper limit for the intersection. and since the smallest value for [] = 0.0 , the smallest value for [] = 0.0, then then 0.0X0.0 = 0.0 would the lower limit for the intersection.  Leading us to the conclusion: [∩] take any value in that interval [0, 0.25]

Comment: It is very possible.  Remember that an event is just a subset of the sample space.  So you need to find $X \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and $Y \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Comment: are you saying that it is possible for  [∩] to have a value greater than 0.25?

Comment: Yes.  One rule of constructing mathematical examples is KISS: Keep it Simple and Specific.  I have suggested a simple and specific example of a dice roll with 6 possible outcomes, but for some reason you have ignored that example. Is it that you do not like that example?

Comment: Honestly, I could not relate that example to the original problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you are studying probability, you must have seen examples of rolling a dice and asking "What is the probability the roll is even?" and so on.  I am asking you to choose a specific subset of $\{1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6\}$ and you are giving up.

Comment: What is the probability the roll is even? of course, that would be 0.5.  If you mean choose randomly, then I will let X represent the event of getting {1,2,3} and Y represents the event of getting {4,5,6} with [] = 0.5 and [] = 0.5. I am not sure if I am following your question correctly or not?

Comment: Yes, so then the criteria $P[X] \leq 0.5$ and $P[Y] \leq 0.5$ is met. What is $P[X \cap Y]$ in that specific case?  Then, can you construct another example of $X, Y$ such that $P[X\cap Y] >0.25$?

Comment: In this case, that would be zero.

Comment: So, by being very simple and specific,  you have proven that it is possible to have $P[X] \leq 0.5$, $P[Y]\leq 0.5$, $P[X \cap Y] = 0$.  Now can you prove the other case is possible? (that is, make $P[X \cap Y] > 0.25$? )

Comment: Let X represent the event that it is going to rain in Seattle, and Y  represents the event that it is going to rain in Portland. with P(X) ≤ 0.5 and P(Y) ≤ 0.5. Assuming these two events are independent of each other, I would conclude [∩] take any value in that interval [0, 0.25].  Since the greatest value for [] = 0.5, the greatest value for [] = 0.5, then 0.5X0.5 = 0.25 would the upper limit for the intersection. and since the smallest value for [] = 0.0 , the smallest value for [] = 0.0, then then 0.0X0.0 = 0.0 would the lower limit for the intersection.

Comment: I was not expecting you to change the probability experiment.  Can you stick to the same example of the dice roll?  Just choose different subsets of $\{1, ...., 6\}$.

Comment: with dice example, if we let X represent odd numbers {1,3,5}. And Y represent all numbers except 6 such that tha sample space = {1,2,3,4,5}. then, then the intersection would would be, 3/5 which is greater than 0.25

Comment: would you agree with the conclusion in the rain example?

Comment: The problem in your new example is that $P[Y]=P[\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}] >0.5$.  You are looking to find $X$ and $Y$ such that $P[X] \leq 0.5$, $P[Y]\leq 0.5$, $P[X \cap Y] > 0.25$.  Examples of this are not hard to find, but so far you have not found one.

Comment: I see,  if we let X represent odd numbers {1,3,5}. And Y  reprsent the following set = {1,2,3}. then, then the intersection would = 2/5 which is greater than 0.25

Comment: Minor issue:  Please compute $X \cap Y$ and $P[X \cap Y]$ (I don't know where your $2/5$ number is coming from)

Comment: ∩  = {1,3}  and  [∩] = 2/5. two is coming from the number of elements in ∩  = {1,3},  and five is coming from the total number of elements in both sets {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: The probability of rolling either a 1 or a 3 is not equal to $2/5$.

Comment: We have a standard dice.  The sample space is $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.  All outcomes are equally likely.  The probabilitiy of $\{1,3\}$ is not 2/5.

Comment: it has to be 2/6 = 1/3 which is still greater than 0.25

Comment: Okay, so now you have a simple and specific example that it is possible to have $P[X]\leq 0.5$, $P[Y]\leq 0.5$, $P[X \cap Y] > 0.25$.  [Of course, you previously argued that this was **impossible** so hopefully you see that your previous argument was faulty.]  Can you get higher than $2/6$?  How high can you go?

Comment: I see, I think in this case the highest I can go is if X and Y represent the same set of numbers. Such that X represents the event of getting {1,2,3}  and Y represent the same event of getting {1,2,3}. leading to the conclusion that [∩]=0.5

Comment: Yes.  And you cannot go higher than $0.5$ because $$ X \cap Y \subseteq X \implies P[X \cap Y] \leq P[X] $$ and we are told that $P[X] \leq 0.5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!! :)

Comment: would you agree with my conclusion in the rain example?

Comment: Let X represent the event that it is going to rain in Seattle, and Y represents the event that it is going to rain in Portland. with P(X) ≤ 0.5 and P(Y) ≤ 0.5. Assuming these two events are independent of each other, I would conclude [∩] take any value in that interval [0, 0.25]. Since the greatest value for [] = 0.5, the greatest value for [] = 0.5, then 0.5X0.5 = 0.25 would the upper limit for the intersection. and since the smallest value for [] = 0.0 , the smallest value for [] = 0.0, then then 0.0X0.0 = 0.0 would the lower limit for the intersection.